# Setting attribute of an object equal to other attributes Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to set one of an objects attributes to be equal to a combination of other attributes.

```
class poly_Uservar(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.long1 = 0
    self.long2 = 0
    self.long3 = 0
    self.long4 = 0
    self.x = 0
    self.command = ''
    self.formats = self.long1,self.long2,self.long3,self.long4
def setUservars(self):
    for self.x in range (0,50):
        decim1 = float(.07)*float(self.x)
        decim2 = float(.07)*float(self.x+1)
        self.long1 = float(float(10.00000) + float(decim1))
        self.long2 = float(float(10.00000) + decim2)
        self.long3 = float(self.long1 +.030000)
        self.long4 = float(self.long3 +.020000)
        cmd = self.command % self.formats
        print cmd

        time.sleep(.2)  
def main():
    type= raw_input('Enter type')
    Uservar = poly_Uservar()
    if type == '3':
        Uservar.command = 'Uservar[%i]: 10.07000 %f 10.01000 %f 9.93000 %f\r'
        Uservar.formats = Uservar.x,Uservar.long1,Uservar.long2,Uservar.long1
        Uservar.setUservar()
    if type == '4':
        Uservar.command = 'Uservar[%i]: 10.07000 %f 10.01000 %f 9.93000 %f 9.93000 %f\r'
        Uservar.formats = Uservar.x,Uservar.long1,Uservar.long2,Uservar.long2,Uservar.long1
        Uservar.setUservar()
```

The issue that I'm running into is that my formats atrribute doesn't get updated to the other attributes as they get set. And I can't reassign them in the for loop because depending on user input the format changes. So cmd always prints out what the other attributes are initialized too. Is there a way to force my code to update my formats attribute as they change in my method? 
Thanks in advace!

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to set the command to a list somehow? and then I can iterate over the list?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I eventually came up with a solution that works. It is not very "pythonic", however, so If someone has a better way of doing it I still would love to see:) Anyways here's what I ended up doing.

```
class poly_Uservar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.long1 = 0
        self.long2 = 0
        self.long3 = 0
        self.long4 = 0
        self.command = ''
        self.formats = [1,2,3]

def setUservars(self):
    for self.x in range (0,50):
        for x in range (0,50):
            decim1 = float(.07)*float(x)
            decim2 = float(.07)*float(x+1)
            self.long1 = float(float(10.00000) + float(decim1))
            self.long2 = float(float(10.00000) + decim2)
            self.long3= float(self.long1 +.030000)
            self.long4= float(self.long3 +.020000)
            vals = [self.long1, self.long2, self.long3, self.long4]
            cmd_args = [x]
            for i in range (0, len(self.formats)):
                cmd_args.append(vals[self.formats[i]-1])
            cmd = self.command % tuple(cmd_args)            
            print cmd
def main():
    type= raw_input('Enter type')
    Uservar = poly_Uservar()
    if type == '3':
        Uservar.command = ':Uservar[%i] 10.07000 %f 10.01000 %f 9.93000 %f\r'
        Uservar.formats = [1,2,1]
        Uservar.setUservar()
```